# Why does data in my JavaScript class is undefined when calling it from a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have in an external JavasScript (sun.js) file a class like this :

```
export default class Sun {
   constructor(){
      this.text = 'I\'m shining!';
   }
    
    static testIfShining() {
       console.log("is the sun shining?");
       console.log(this.text);
    }
 }
```

So I'm importing this class in one of my component

```
import Sun from '../sun.js'
```

And then I call my function `testIfShining()` in my mounted lifecycle :

```
mounted() {
   Sun.testIfShining();
}
```

When I look at my console, I have the message log

```
is the sun shining?
undefined
```

The function is working but I have an undefined value for the data `this.text`

How can I reuse the value inside my constructor? I want to my data works like attribute so I can reuse it in every function in my class.

Comment: Hi, I response to soon this morning. I edit my post, hope it will help.

Comment: You cannot call a static method on an instance. Therefore, trying to use an instance property in a static method does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write/copy your code well here you have to escape the single quote. Like

```js
 this.text = 'I\'m shining!';
```

in your code

```js
export default class Sun {
   constructor(){
      this.text = "I'm shining!"; // <------- Use also double quote
   }
    
   testIfShining() { // <------ remove the static
       console.log("is the sun shining?");
       console.log(this.text);
    }
 }
```

edit: Reply to fast. And also use like this :

Could you try this

```js
mounted() {
   let sun = new Sun();
   sun.testIfShining();
}
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/y4675twv/2/

Comment: I already tried it ! Forgot to say it in my question, sorry. But I have this error : TypeError: sun.testIfShining is not a function

Comment: Look my post, i just edit. Static function cannot use ***this***

Comment: Cool. Just mark my answer check. Enjoy coding. 